# When date is approaching (1 week) Change colour of worksheet tab

Tags: excel, vba

As titile describes, this is what i got so far.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)

Dim i As Long

Dim cell As Date

For i = 14 To MAX_ROW
    cell = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 14).Value
    If DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(cell), Day(cell)) - Date <= 7 Then
    Sh.Tab.ColorIndex = 3
    Else
    Sh.Tab.ColorIndex = 6
    End If
   Next
 
End Sub
```

What i have is a table for car inspections. In the table there is two columns one for the date inspection is completed and the second for when the next inspection is due. In the case of the code when the inspection is due is in column 14 (the table also starts in row 14 so thats why i have i = 14) and what i think my code does is that it searches that column until the if condition is met (sorry if im wrong i started very recently). Since there is a few vehicles instead of checking each sheet on at the time i want it so that the worksheet tab color changes once the duye date is close (in this case 7 days later).

[image: Image of sample data]

Thats what the table looks like the column in the right is the next due date which is calculated with formula =IF(M14="";"";DATE(YEAR(M14);MONTH(M14)+6;DAY(M14)))
Which adds 6 months to the date added in the column to the left (which is the completion of the previous car checkup) so therefore the right one is now when the next check is due.

Comment: What the title nor the post describes is the problem and there is no question.  Please see [mcve]

Comment: Also you are changing the tab colour max_row-14 times, so only the last date will affect the tab color you are left with.  Agree with scott, hard to tell what you want/issues are.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question i have updated the question and hopefully it is more clear. The sh.cells and max_row i got from researching in the internet and trying many different ways to try and make the code work. So it might not fit in what i actually want to do (im still a beginner)

Comment: Also the table as i described, will continously keep updating so when the inspection that was due is completed the tab colour changes back again to the default color meaning that the cars inspection is done.

Comment: Please provide a full example data set (screenshots might help here a lot). Then explain how your data changes and when and what should happen in each step. Try to explain to precise as detailed as possible. Without example data it is very hard to understand your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have added a screenshot of the table and some further explanation, hope this helps understand if anything else is needed to understand please let me know and i will try and explain further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: checks to see if the service date is less than 7 days in the future and not marked as "Completado" in the next cell to the right.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)

    Const MAX_ROW As Long = 40 'for example
    
    Dim i As Long, dt, c As Range
    
    Sh.Tab.ColorIndex = 6              'default color
    For i = 14 To MAX_ROW
        Set c = Sh.Cells(i, 14)
        dt = c.Value                   'Sh not Activesheet
        If IsDate(dt) Then             'check is a date
            Debug.Print Sh.Name, i, dt
            'is the service date within 7 days from now and not already completed?
            If Date - Sh.Cells(i, 14).Value < 7 And _
                     LCase(Trim(c.Offset(0, 1).Value)) <> "completado" Then
                Sh.Tab.Color = vbRed
                Exit Sub               'done after one change
            End If
        End If
    Next i
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This code works much better! Everything works except that the colour changes to red (ColorIndex = 3) in dates that it shouldn't, such as a month or two months before the date and not seven days like i was trying to get to do. Not sure if it is the part of    Sh.Cells(i, 14).Value - Date <= 7   that is making this be the case. Thanks again for help!

Comment: See edit above - fixed the date check part

Comment: Hello thanks again im pretty sure the code is improving however it is still changing the color of the tab in the wrong times. When researching ways of doing this code previously i stumbled across a code that used this   If DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(cell), Day(cell)) - Date <= 7 Then   Not sure if this could solve it or how this line of code could be implemented in the code you did

Comment: Hello again, after looking into it i found out that the IF to work in this case it should be: If dt - Date < 7 And dt - Date >= 0 Then... This would make it not go crazy if it goes less than 0. Now i was wondering if by any chance there is a way of making it so that when in the case that the inspection was made before the expected due date or when the inspection is done in general, to reset the colour to default since that inspection has been done already. This cant be done now since the code is still reading the previous date in the table since it meets the IF condition.

Comment: I have another column in the table that states "Completed" when a date in the next cell is added underneath the previous one.  https://i.imgur.com/S1KIYzC.png  here is a screenshot of what i mean, i also have it conditionally formatted to green. Here is a more complete table: https://i.imgur.com/TeJsKbg.png . Maybe by having this completed cell next to the date what i want to achieve gets easier. Im not sure how to code it though.

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry to bother again but is there a way to rerun the code for it  to see that there is the "completed". Since when i first put a date it doesnt have the completed until a put another date. And when i put another date the code doesnt seem to see that there is now a "completed" next to it and it stays red, its like if its not updating live to whats happening. So maybe if there is a way to rerun the code again so it sees that there is now a completed and that the color should go back to default? Thank you very much again.

Comment: If you press F9 it will calculate the worksheet and the color will correct...

Comment: Doesn't seem to correct in my case. https://i.imgur.com/KFQHx5Y.png Even though there is another date the color stays the same. You have helped a ton already, right now i feel like im really bothering you im very sorry for that.